# How does one "separate" the cartesian product properly?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Say, $\delta>0$, $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $(x_0,y_0)\in X \times Y $, and there is some property $P$ such that

$$\forall (x,y) \in X \times Y: \ \ \ \  d \Big( (x_0,y_0), (x,y) \Big) < \delta \implies P $$

I am interested in "separating" $ X \times Y $: defining such $A \subset X, B \subset Y$ that

$$\forall x \in A \ \ \ \ \forall y \in B:  \ \  d \Big( (x_0,y_0), (x,y) \Big) < \delta$$

Can we always state something like: $ \exists \alpha, \beta>0$ such that

$$A:= \{x \in X : d_A(x,x_0)< \alpha  \}$$
$$B:= \{y \in Y : d_B(y,y_0)< \beta  \}$$

do the job?

Comment: Assuming that the metric $d$ induces the product topology on $X\times Y$, yes, since that ball with radius $\delta$ around $(x_0,y_0)$ is a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, there are neighbourhoods $A$ of $x_0$ and $B$ of $y_0$ such that $A\times B$ is contained in the ball. You can of course choose $A$ and $B$ as balls.